# MySQL tables altered after server reboot

Tags: php, mysql, sql, reboot, bonfire

The last two times my production server reboot, I noticed some of my MySQL database tables had been changed.

I'm using CI Bonfire on PHP 5 server. The concerned tables are users, permissions, role_permissions and settings. These 4 tables are reset to their initial structure every time the server reboot. The users table does not loose any data (last users registered are still their) but some fields are missing. The other tables are reset (structure + data) to their initial state too.

I searched something about CI Bonfire migrations but nothing yet...

I have also a development server on which the problem does not occur...

Any idea on what it can be from ?

Comment: That sounds bad. Why would columns go "missing"? Is there something running that *actively* modifies the schema so?

Comment: I may have found something... I discovered a config variable "migrate.auto_core" setter to true. I'm exploring the migration library to see what the impact is.

Comment: any security software like deepfreeze installed?

Comment: Nop, nothing like this.

As I said, I have explored what the config variable found before was triggering. It seems to check the last version of the tables stored in the migrations modules folders and "up" or "down" version to match. I have then set it to false.